# Некорректная работа линтера C++ в Vusual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, синтаксис, linter

Библиотека `windows.h`.

Объявляю и инициализирую класс окна:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
```

Присваиваю полю структуры значение:

```
wc.lpszClassName = "test";
```

Сразу подчеркивается в редакторе красным, ошибка:

> значение типа "const char *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "LPCWSTR"

Дописываю "L" перед строковым литералом:

```
wc.lpszClassName = L"test";
```

Редактор больше не ругается.

Компилирую:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Ошибка компиляции:

> error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t* const' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'} in assignment

Убираю "L". Редактор снова ругается, но компиляция проходит успешно, а программа работает. Я, как перфекционист, испытываю отвращение, видя подчеркнутые ошибки. Как это исправить? Отключить совсем - не вариант, иногда очень даже помогает.

Comment: Кажется, переключение между широкими строками и обычными делается макросом `UNICODE`. Посмотрите, в какое значение его устаналивает гцц по умолчанию, и поставьте то же значение в настройках интеллисенса.

Comment: Еще советую посмотреть в сторону Clangd вместо стандартного интеллисенса. Он местами сыроват, но с ним таких проблем не возникает в принципе. (Особенно если в качестве компилятора взять кланг, но с гцц тоже должет работать нормально.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Если навести на "UNICODE" в редакторе, то написано "Expands to 1". Но при попытке скомпилировать `cout << UNICODE;` - ошибка компиляции. "UNICODE was not declarated in this scope"

Comment: Значит надо как-то заставить интеллисенс не устанавливать `UNICODE` в 1. Как именно - не знаю, потому что не пользуюсь.